# How can I run or add javascript code to asp web page from .vb (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net

Regards,

I need to add or run javascript to ASP web page, but this javascript code I need to add or run from .vb before web page started.

Comment: Did you try Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to add some script in the page load event

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    If Not Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("demoscript") Then
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.Append(vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & vbCrLf)
        sb.Append(" put your js script here")
        sb.Append("</script>" & vbCrLf)

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "demoscript", sb.ToString)
    End If
  End If
```